# Interceptor Observable not running

Tags: angular

I'm at a total loss as to why my interceptor which returns an observable is not executing and then finally, emitting the next handler observable.

I'm clearly missing a fundamental aspect so debugging is becoming a case for re reading tutorial so any help will be appreciated to help this process along.

Here is the code:

```
constructor(private tokenAuthService: TokenAuthService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(`Auth INterceptor`);
    return this.tokenAuthService.token
      .map(token => {
        console.log(`Setting token ${token}`);
        return req.clone({ 'headers': req.headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`) });
      })
      .concatMap(request => {
        console.log(`Returning Request`);
        return next.handle(request);
      })
      .catch((err: Error, observable) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
          return Observable.concat(this.tokenAuthService.refreshToken, observable);
        }
        console.log(`Auth Interceptor Error: ${err.message}`);
        throw err;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, if it's not executing, that has nothing to do with the code of the interceptor. It has to do with how you register the interceptor, in your module.

Comment: can you show your app.module.ts file?

Comment: I apologise, it was the app module file, forgot to register the interceptor!

Answer (score 0):

By registering the interceptor correctly the code executed.